# 1976 Baltimore bridge collision with cargo ship

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, steel

Of course no bridge would survive impact with a very heavy tonnage vessel moving horizontally and knocking out support piers as the bridge structural design is based on vertical gravity dead load / wind loads.

The following is about redundancy concerns of modern building practice. If we consider static balance of the central portion of the bridge on either side of the two piers  the entire weight appears counteracted by 4 (simply supported/ sliding) supports or pivots. While design is quite adequate and worked well since 1976 it is particularly weak against horizontal impact. The video shows sheared cut sections pivoting down during fall.

Shocking update: The bridge is designed *fracture critical* or *without any redundancy*, meaning *a local  structural failure can lead to a local or global destruction*... according to NTSB.

However some lessons? lateral thoughts... pictures post Baltimore bridge collision show separation of horizontal road deck from the other three remaining trusses in the box girders. The road deck appears suspended from arch  above by flimsy tubes or steel cables. Accident footage shows vertical distance between arch and road deck widening during fall. Also neatly separated box girders of 4 or 5 span sections are visible around river pier supports.

The connections between box girder and road may have been rusted or the suspension elements joints compromised with corrosion.

Is not the truss reinforcement around deck structurally more important than elsewhere? What protocol is in place for evaluating stiffness integrity evaluation from time to time? Is sufficient maintenance attention given to post construction structural strength and stiffness in design reviews?

After Tacoma Narrows bridge experience elsewhere the plate girder was abandoned as a stiffening element found to be ineffective and inefficient and instead replaced by web trusses or box girders adopted to provide more stiffness and aerodynamic stability. Small but repeated twist/torque from  partially disconnected road deck induced vortices could contribute to collapse in the longrun.

Comment: Why don't you wait for the official reports about what actually happened before guessing what might have gone wrong?

Comment: why is your update "shocking?"

Comment: The bridge  anti collision pylon protection appears compromised. Redundancy design was not taken up in retrospect for strength upgrades including redundancy. Agreed it is just hindsight.

Comment: Waiting for official reports. My concern is about horizontal loads bridge can carry to be included as design specification.